# Dynamic Model Binding Partial View to Model MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm trying to bind the model from the partial view to my main form. My Model `workoutPlan` only stores a list of WorkoutSets

`public List<WorkoutSet> WorkoutSet;`

In my main page. My form looks something like this:

```
@model WorkoutPlanObjects.WorkoutPlan
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewPlan", "Workout", FormMethod.Post))
{

if (Model != null)
{
    <table id="workoutTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Partial/_AddNewPlan.cshtml", Model);}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

}
```

and here's my partial view `_AddNewPlan`

```
@model WorkoutPlanObjects.WorkoutPlan

@if(Model!=null)
{ 
       foreach (var item in Model.WorkoutSet)
       {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => item.Repeats)
       }            
}
```

I was able to update my partial view using ajax calls but when I try to submit the form, no values get passed. Here's the snippet of the code in chrome which shows the rendered partial view (excuse the formatting). Any solution for this?

I could see that the name of the rendered views are all the same `item.Repeats`. How should I change this partial view name to bind with the main page model?

```
<form action="/Workout/AddNewPlan" method="post">    

    <table id="workoutTable">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>
              <input id="item_Repeats" name="item.Repeats" type="text" value="1">
              <input id="item_Repeats" name="item.Repeats" type="text" value="2">
              <input id="item_Repeats" name="item.Repeats" type="text" value="3">
              <input id="item_Repeats" name="item.Repeats" type="text" value="4">
            </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `foreach` loop to a `for` loop so that the inputs are correctly named

```
foreach (iny i = 0; i < Model.WorkoutSet.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.WorkoutSet[i].Repeats)
}
```

which will render

```
<input .... name="WorkoutSet[0].Repeats" type="text" value="1">
<input .... name="WorkoutSet[1].Repeats" type="text" value="2">
```

and allow the `DefaultModelBinder` to bind the collection.

Note property `WorkoutSet` will need to be `IList`. Alternatively you can create a custom `EditorTemplate` for `WorkoutSet` and use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.WorkoutSet)`